# Make Float elements inline

Tags: css, css-float, inline

I have some blocks in my footer and want to make them inline. But with `display: block` it's doesn't work because i also had `float: right` property. If i remove it, then all my footer design breaks. How can i safely make blocks inline without breaking my design?

Here is link on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GNz8d/

Tryed add width, height but it had affected only on size of block, not on inline of element.

Elements with class `.footer-block` i wanna make inline.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what exactly you are asking for here.  How exactly do you want the elements different than what I see in your fiddle?

Comment: Could you add a diagram of your expected output

Comment: http://rghost.net/56910972.view here is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the clear from the footer class:

```
.footer-container #footer .footer-block {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

And then set your top div to 100% width:

```
#footer #newsletter_block_left {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 13px 15px 7px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yffcp/2/